# ng-click doesnt work with angularui tooltip

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm fairly new to angular and trying to show some html content inside a angular-ui tooltip. what i need to implement is something like a dashboard where users can click icons and go to different urls inside the application.

but for some reason ng-click doesnt work inside the tooltip body content. here is my code.

```
<a tooltip-html-unsafe="{{htmlTooltip}}" tooltip-trigger="click" tooltip-placement="bottom" >Dashboard</a>
```

in controller

$scope.htmlTooltip = 'HRIS';

```
$scope.dosomething() = function() {
    console.log("hello World");
};
```

how can i accomplish this task. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is here:

```
$scope.dosomething() = function() {
    console.log("hello World");
};
```

You need to change it like this (delete brackets):

```
$scope.dosomething = function() {
    console.log("hello World");
};
```

Also, it's better if you will add `href="#"` to your `a` tag, then cursor will be looking like a pointer.

If you need to call you `dosomething` function every time you click on the `Dashboard` link - you need to add `ng-click="dosomething()"` to your `a` tag.
So finally it will be looking like this:

```
<a href="#" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{htmlTooltip}}" ng-click="dosomething()" tooltip-trigger="click" tooltip-placement="bottom">Dashboard</a>
```

and controller:

```
$scope.htmlTooltip = 'HRIS';

$scope.dosomething = function() {
    console.log("hello World");
};
```

You can see demo, here everything works OK:

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/guQiOUUjuj4fGJDwFBKE?p=preview

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. what i need exactly is to fire the ng-click inside the tooltip. so the $scope.htmlTooltip  should contain the ng-cilck html code.

Comment: @Chathruaka Waas : You are welcome:) And you can mark answer as accepted if it really helped you :)

Comment: hi acutually this is not what i want to accomplish. what i want is to place ng-click inside the tooltip body content.